# arrow keys not scrolling on IE7 for our web site

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

we have a live production site in which IE7 users complain that they cannot use the arrow keys / page up / page down to scroll around on a page. it works perfectly for IE6/IE8/FF/Opera/Chrome, but not for ie7
This happens on all the pages in the solution
any ideas?

the site is found on [www.rikstoto.no](http://www.rikstoto.no)

Yours
Andreas Knudsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the

```
body { overflow: auto !important }
```

line from `ie7Styles.css`